# Making bar widths and gaps consistent in dc.js when using a large dataset and d3.scale.linear()

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

When creating a barchart using dc.js and a smaller dataset, I can get the bars and gaps to look pretty consistent.

When using a larger dataset and d3.scale.linear(), I haven't been able to get the bars and gaps to look anywhere as nice as when using a Date chart and d3.time.scale().

The bars are either too thin or thick without a gap - http://neil-s.com/unison/crossfilter/test/Crossfilter.jpg

Here is some sample code for one of the top bar charts from my image above:

```
var tempDim = xFilter.dimension(function(d) {return d.temp;}); 
var tempCount = tempDim.group().reduceCount(function(d) {return d.temp;}); 
var minTemp = tempDim.bottom(1)[0].temp;
var maxTemp = tempDim.top(1)[0].temp;   

tempBarChart    
        .width(375).height(157)         
        .dimension(tempDim) 
        .group(tempCount)       
        .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([minTemp, maxTemp]))    
        .centerBar(true)
        .elasticX(true)
        .gap(15) 
        .xUnits(function(){return 15;}) 
        .xAxis().ticks(6)
```

I've experimented with the gap, xUnits, and ticks values, but no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not pretty!

This is a known bug with dc.js.

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/952

I think it works slightly better in 1.7 than in the 2.0 development branch, but it is still not perfect.

The only thing I can think of as a workaround for now is to create a renderlet which adjusts the widths after the fact. :-(

Comment: I have seen some related posts on other sites that made me think this was a bug. Thanks for your work on dc.js, Gordon. I'm looking forward to version 2.  :)

Comment: Gordon, do you know if this is an issue with other dc.js charts as well? I'm working on a line chart using d3.scale.linear() as the x axis domain. Like the bar chart, it looks much better with a smaller dataset than a larger one:
http://neil-s.com/unison/crossfilter/test/LineCharts.jpg

Comment: I don't think that's the same problem.  Actually, I'm not sure how you would get a nice drawing of a line chart with so many spikes, except by zooming in. :-/  If you have any suggestions, [create an issue](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/new)

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for getting back to me, Gordon.

Comment: Just in case this helps someone else, I found a solution for my scenario. All of the data values in the json file I received had 2 decimal places. Once I removed those decimal places, both the line chart and bar chart looked much better with the large dataset.

Comment: I am running into the same issue with the latest dc.js, 2.0.0-beta.12. Are there any plans to fix this issue in 2.0.0 branch

Comment: Hi @Nathan. That code is very brittle, so I am not sure if it can go into 2.0 or if it will require a rewrite and a change of interface, which would put it in 2.1. But yes, I do intend to fix it. Just a question of finding the time. If you see a good fix, PRs are always welcome!

Comment: Too bad the links are dead. Should have copied those screenshots into the question!